# Async, Azure and program flow

Tags: azure, asynchronous, task, azure-mobile-services

I have searched this forum for my problem but didn't find anything that suited, Im having a problem with my program flow.

I have a MobileService on Azure that has a question table, my app has a main menu and quiz button that takes the user to the quiz page, on the quiz page I have a start quiz button that shows the first question in the list.

This is the code im using to get the questions from the database, I placed it in the pages constructor and now when the user presses the quiz button there is a delay in the page opening which isn't that bad as its not a long wait, only a few seconds, is there a better way to do this?

```
Task<IMobileServiceTable<Question>> getDataFromDatabase = new Task<IMobileServiceTable<Question>>(getQuestions);
getDataFromDatabase.Start();
QuestionList = await getDataFromDatabase;
```

In the same function I have this code which modifies the start quiz button isEnabled attribute. This stops the quiz going forward unless the data has came through from the server, but its not working all the time and sometimes the start button isenabled is set to true and I get nullreference from my MobileServiceCollectionView QuestionList even though the task has completed.

```
Task<bool> assignData = new Task<bool>(assignTabletoitems);
assignData.Start();
startbutton.IsEnabled = await assignData;
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to create a new instance of `Task<T>` to query the database (you haven't provided the definition of `getQuestions` which is used in your first code snippet, so I can't tell whether that code is doing what it's supposed to). What you'd typically do is to get a table for the appropriate type from the `MobileServiceClient` object, and then query on it:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient(appUrl, appKey);
var table = client.GetTable<Question>();
var questionList = await table.ToListAsync();
```

Regarding your second code snippet, without the definition of `assignTabletoitems` it's really hard to know what you're intending that code to do.